# TypeScript project can't compile to a proper index.js

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build the TypeScript project [here](https://github.com/simpleledger/BitcoinFilesJS) as

```
git clone https://github.com/simpleledger/BitcoinFilesJS.git test/
cd test
npm i
tsc # or npx tsc
```

The `index.js` created is this:

```js
"use strict";
var __createBinding = (this && this.__createBinding) || (Object.create ? (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    Object.defineProperty(o, k2, { enumerable: true, get: function() { return m[k]; } });
}) : (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    o[k2] = m[k];
}));
var __exportStar = (this && this.__exportStar) || function(m, exports) {
    for (var p in m) if (p !== "default" && !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(exports, p)) __createBinding(exports, m, p);
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
__exportStar(require("./lib/bfp"), exports);
__exportStar(require("./lib/utils"), exports);
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

However, if I install the project as in a new directory with `npm i bitcoinfiles`, the index.js is:

```js
let bfp = require('./lib/bfp');
let utils = require('./lib/utils');
let network = require('./lib/network');

module.exports = {
    bfp: bfp,
    utils: utils, 
    network: network
}
```

What could be causing TypeScript to generate my unclean index.js? In addition, they don't work. As you can see, the unclean `index.js` doesn't define `module.exports`

Comment: You need to use the [build script](https://github.com/simpleledger/BitcoinFilesJS/blob/master/package.json#L13) defined in the `package.json`

Comment: No, that doesn't work, it invokes tsc which is what fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recreated the index.js successfully from a checkout of the release-tagged code at https://github.com/simpleledger/BitcoinFilesJS/tree/0.5.0 by running `npm run build`

```
let bfp = require('./lib/bfp');
let utils = require('./lib/utils');
let network = require('./lib/network');

module.exports = {
    bfp: bfp,
    utils: utils, 
    network: network
}
```

Be aware that the main/master branch of any repo might be where work is going on, and released versions could be different. Currently the main branch of this repo seems to target ES5 which transpiles differently.

Currently this only builds successfully by manually creating the `dist` directory and probably requires manual install of `typescript` and `browserify` which I guess is just installed globally in the authors machine so they didn't realise they were missing these dependencies.